# Is it possible to disable Ctrl+V in windows?

Tags: delphi, hook, keyboard-hook, keyboard-shortcuts

How can i disable `Ctrl+V` shortcut-key in windows and handle it by my own application? Actually , i want to ignore it and send another key instead of `Ctrl+V`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`RegisterHotKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28VS.85%29.aspx) to do this.

Comment: But Ctrl+V is already reserved in windows. is it anyway possible?

Comment: Ctrl+V is not reserved by windows. Only WindowsKey+ combinations are reserved. You can do this even though I can't imagine why you would want to.

Comment: IIRC Win key combination is not reserved too, but rather registered as hotkeys.

Comment: @David Thank you. The first part of my question was : How to disable Ctrl+V? Suppose you're working with the notepad and then you press Ctrl+V. Now, is it possible to ignore(disable) it?

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. When you register a hot key, you steal it from all other apps. You can choose to do nothing. I am curious though, why do you want to force the user to use the menus or Ctrl+Insert in order to paste.e user to use the menus or Ctrl+Insert in order to paste.

Comment: And registering a hot-key needs administrator privilege. right?

Comment: In fact, i want to make a utility that helps users to create and manage different clipboards at the same time. And now there is a new question! how can i give Ctrl+V back to the windows when my application is turned off?

Comment: The answer to that one is UnregisterHotKey.

Comment: `UnRegisterHotkey()` when your app exits.